# Can I move the vertical scrollbar away slightly from the content text within the div container?

Tags: html, css

I would like to be able to shift the scrollbar on [this website](http://www.strangerandstranger.com/wiston/site/people3.html)
to the right, away from the text, by about `20px` or more.
Is this possible?

Comment: Add some `padding-right` to the div that contains the text.

Comment: _"Is this possible?"_ Sure, but what have __you__ tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend just adding some padding like so:

Change:

```
<div style="width: 450px; height: 500px; overflow: auto;">
```

To:

```
<div style=" width: 430px; padding-right:20px; height: 500px; overflow: auto;">
```